# SQL to get the distinct rolling sum over a growing window

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that shows the inventory records per day. I need to get the rolling distinct  and its total. How can I get it? recursive SQL?

Here I have a simplified table like this:

```
SELECT timestamp, item FROM inventory;
```

| timestamp | item |
| --- | --- |
| 20210101 | A |
| 20210101 | B |
| 20210101 | C |
| 20210102 | A |
| 20210103 | B |
| 20210103 | D |

The [timestamp] is the timestamp when we receive the inventory stock. The [item] is the item name. for the first row:
on 2021 Jan 1st, we have A,B and C.
on 2021-01-02, we got A.
on 2021-02-03, we got B and C.

Expected results:
**Table1**:

| Time | distinct_item_count(rolling) |
| --- | --- |
| 20210101 | 3 |
| 20210102 | 3 |
| 20210103 | 4 |

**Table2**:

| Time | distinct_item |
| --- | --- |
| 20210101 | A,B,C |
| 20210102 | A,B,C |
| 20210103 | A,B,C,D |

This means, up to 20210101,
we have (A,B and C),
20210102 -> (A,B,C),
20210103 -> (A,B,C,D)

Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `select distinct timestamp, (select count(distinct item) from inventory i2 where i2.timestamp <= i.timestamp) as distinct_item_count from inventory i`

Comment: Hi, MSSQL and big query later.

Answer (score 0):

your example data not match with the results...
sql server solution below

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
  timestamp varchar(8),
  item varchar(1)
 );
 
 insert into inventory(timestamp, item) values
('20210101','A'),
('20210101','A'),
('20210101','B'),
('20210101','C'),
('20210102','A'),
('20210103','B'),
('20210103','D');


select timestamp,  sum(qtd) as qtd, string_agg(item,',') items
from(
select 
 timestamp, item, 1 qtd
 from inventory
 group by timestamp, item) s
 group by timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not what I am after.